# app organization

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to keep my layouts organized? I am accumulating quite a few and it is getting a little confusing. I tried to create folders and put them in there, but the references got all messed up and couldn't do that.

Any help?

Comment: Its not possible to have folders in layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to make sure everything is named correctly.

> activity_layout_foo.xml
>
> fragment_layout_foo.xml
>
> dialog_layout_foo.xml
>
> list_item_foo.xml

I also try to use include and merge whenever possible http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: I have everything named correctly, and that helps, but the way it is working out, I will have over 100 activities lol